# Question about reflective construction in SEMinR

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I am running `estimate_pls()` followed by `summary()`. They work when I construct the measurement models as "composite". However, one of the models should be reflective. When I make it reflective, `estimate.pls()` works but not `summary()`, which throws this error:

```
Error in solve.default(construct_score_cors[c(independant, dependant[i]),  : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 0
In addition: Warning message:
In sqrt(rho %*% t(rho)) : NaNs produced
```

Can someone help diagnose the error and suggest ways to resolve it?

```r
## Model 1
simple_mm <- constructs(
  composite("URBAN", multi_items("urban_", 1:2)),
  composite("EFFICACY_AGENCY", multi_items("efficacy.agency_", 1:2), weights = correlation_weights),
  composite("ROLE", single_item("Role"), weights = correlation_weights),
  composite("VALUES", single_item("values_avg"), weights = correlation_weights),
  composite("TL", single_item("TL.Score"), weights = correlation_weights))

## Reflective measurement model: the indicators are caused by latent variables.
##  Formative measurement model: the measured variables are the cause of the latent variable.

reflec_mm <- as.reflective(simple_mm) # this does not help
 
## Create a structural model
simple_sm <- relationships(
  paths(from = c("URBAN"), to = c("EFFICACY_AGENCY", "ROLE", "VALUES")),
  paths(from = c("EFFICACY_AGENCY", "ROLE", "VALUES"), to = c("TL")))

## Estimate the model
TL_simple_model <- estimate_pls(
  data = TL_data.scaled,
  measurement_model = simple_mm,
  structural_model = simple_sm,
  inner_weights = path_weighting)
  #missing = mean_replacement,
  #missing_value = "-99")

## Summarize the model results
summary_simple_TL <- summary(TL_simple_model)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This might not be possible to answer without a [mcve] ...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).